# Bulma and Fontawesome: How to align icons vertically and horizontally?

Tags: css, alignment, font-awesome, bulma

I've recently started to experiment with Bulma and Fontawesome, and I found tricky to align the icons vertically and horizontally. My situation is the following.

1. I downloaded Bulma via npm: `npm i bulma --save-dev`;
2. I imported the relevant Fontawesome file as per the [Bulma Docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/): `<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>`;
3. Created a basic input element field with an icon on the left and another on the right:

> ```
> <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
>     <input class="input" type="text">
>     <span class="icon is-small is-left">
>         <i class="fas fa-map-pin"></i>
>     </span>
>     <span class="icon is-small is-right">
>         <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
>     </span>
> </div>
> ```

That resulted in the icons to be weirdly aligned to the top-left corner of their respective positions. I tried to center them by appending a `has-text-centered` class to the span element but that didn't work. Any workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center elements vertically in Bulma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064526/center-elements-vertically-in-bulma)

Comment: Your own answer is pretty much an exact duplicate of the answer in the duplicate

Comment: @Mark I saw that, but this is a specific issue with Font Awesome icons and I thought about sharing my solution.

Comment: @Mark The accepted answer there doesn't mention `align-items: center`, which is exactly what worked for me.

Comment: The first comment under that accepted answer mentions `align-items: center`

Comment: @Mark, ok, now I saw it. How to proceed now? I thought about a specific solution for Font Awesome which is not specifically (I love this adverb) addressed there. Since you're clearly more experienced than me (3k+ reps vs. 61), should I delete my question? Cheers.

Comment: If other people agree that it's a duplicate it'll be marked as duplicate, and then it'll be handled aswell :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found and applied a working solution just by targeting the span element in my CSS file and by making it a flex-container:

```
.icon {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, I found the following in the current [Bulma documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/icon/#icon-text):

> You can combine an icon with text, using the icon-text wrapper, as long as all text inside is wrapped in its own span element:

```html
<span class="icon-text">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
  </span>
  <span>Home</span>
</span>
```